# D3 Selection Highlight (efficiency?)

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple visual of many rects, over 100 I'd say. For aesthetic purposes I want to create a high light effect on mouse click. I also wanted to make this effect somewhat intuitive by removing that effect once the user clicks on a new rect. However I couldn't get this to work without resorting to a `d3.selectAll()` call, so I'm thinking this approach might not be ideal if this project gets any bigger. Here is the code:

```
.on('click.highlight', function() {
//set any previously highlighted rects back to normal color/brightness
    d3.selectAll('.highlight').transition().duration(250)
        .style('fill', function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color)})

    d3.select(this).classed('highlight',true);

//now it's safe to assign the current highlighted rect a brighter hue... i think
    d3.select(this).transition().duration(250)
        .style('fill', function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).brighter(.5)})
})
```

Though this code does what I wanted it to do, but presumably there could only ever be 1 other `highlight` rect to worry about at any give time. So again, I'm not sure that using `d3.selectAll()` is warranted here.

So anyway, is there a more efficient way? I'd like to keep it all within one `.on('click')` function if possible.

Comment: The only change I would make is to limit the selection.  Instead of `d3.selectAll`, use an existing parent selection of your `rect`.  Something like a `g` or `svg` they are all in.  This limits the underlying query-selector from searching the entire document.

Comment: Why not keep an outer reference to the highlighted rect? https://jsfiddle.net/k9qz8jg7/ No need to fiddle around with classes and do re-selections.

Comment: Arash, despite this question not being exactly *off-topic* here at S.O., since you have a **working code** and you are seeking for advices regarding **best practices** and **efficiency**, you should consider start using Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to avoid use of `.selectAll`, you could create a selection of one `rect` that contains the last clicked rectangle. Each time you click on a rectangle:

1. unhighlight the previously selected highlighted rect
2. update that selection to reflect the most recently clicked rectangle
3. highlight the newly selected rect

I use the variable `highlightedRect` to hold the selection that will allow the above workflow:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",600)
  .attr("height",400);
  
var highlightedRect = d3.select(null);

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(d3.range(1600))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y",function(d) { return Math.floor(d/50)*12; })
  .attr("x",function(d) { return d%50 * 12 })
  .attr("width",11)
  .attr("height",11)
  .attr("stroke","white")
  .on("click",function(d) {
    // Recolor the last clicked rect.
    highlightedRect.attr("fill","black");
    // Color the new one:
    highlightedRect = d3.select(this);
    highlightedRect.attr("fill","steelblue");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510657/d3-selection-highlight-efficiency#comment77983225_45510657). However, I was too lazy to write a full-fledged answer myself and hoped nobody would ask me to do so ;-) Well done!

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it appeared just as I was about to hit the submit button - afterwards I checked the fiddle and saw it was the same solution - have to say I like the randomized rectangle aesthetic.